# Como añadir el atributo required a un @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: vb.net

Quería saber cómo añadir el atributo required a un  `@Html.DropDownListFor`, básicamente lo que me gustaría es que el campo de ese Dropdown se me pinte en rojo los bordes cuando el espacio está vacío.

A continuación pongo el código en lenguaje VB:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.TN_Tipo_Operacion,TryCast(ViewBag.Tipo, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With
 {.title = "Seleccione", .class = "selectpicker", .name =
 "ddlTipoDato", .id = "ddlTipoDato"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías usar para ello las DataAnnotations en tu modelo. Agrega a tu propiedad del modelo el atributo Required. Ejemplo

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Public Class MiModelo
  Private m_Id As Decimal
  <Required(ErrorMessage := "Id es requerido")> _
  Public Property Id() As Decimal
    Get
      Return m_Id
    End Get
    Set
      m_Id = Value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Funciono muy bien gracias

Answer (score 2):

prueba agregando:

> , new {required = "required"}

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.TN_Tipo_Operacion,TryCast(ViewBag.Tipo, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With
     {.title = "Seleccione", .class = "selectpicker", .name =
     "ddlTipoDato", .id = "ddlTipoDato"},new {required = "required"})
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto muchas gracias.

Comment: @MauricioAcon por nada :D te agradeceria que votaras como mejor respuesta ya que serviria de ayuda para otros desarrolladores

Comment: Disculpe Ariel aparecieron los votos?, es que soy nuevo en la comunidad

Comment: aparecio el voto, pero a la respuesta de mas arriba, lo ideal, es que votes a la mejor respuesta, ya que otros integrantes que puedan tener la misma duda que tu, llegen a la solucion de inmediato basandose en la mejor respuesta :D saludos